# Can I restore a Replication Subscriber backup without needing to re-configer/re-initialize

Tags: sql-server, replication, backup

I've been trying to read up on this and there are quite a few of posts about restoring a subscribers' backup on a different machine but my question is about -- in my opinion -- a much more simple situation.

We have a subscriber database that presents a set of large tables for reporting purposes. Suppose 'somehow' something gets messed up and the (transactional) replication process gets broken. (e.g. someone drops a column from one of the replicated tables (hypothetical example, but I suppose this would be fatal ;-) ).

Would I be able to fetch a backup of the subscriber database from the day before, restore it on top of the existing subscriber database and assume that the replication will resume? And even if that would 'work'; would it catch up from the point in time where the backup was made or would I lose all changes between the moment of the backup and the moment the replication got broken?

My guess is this wouldn't work, but I'll gladly be proven wrong. Assuming this wouldn't work; what would be the easiest way to 'restart' from yesterdays backup or should I simply live with a total removal & recreation of the replication? (it's scripted, so not really a disaster)

I know I could 'simply' try it out and see what happens, but I'd rather hear from you guys first before drawing conclusions on a sample-size of 1. (besides, I could get lucky now and end up being screwed in the future)

Thanks,
Roby

PS: I noticed that there is a KEEP_REPLICATION option in the RESTORE command, but it's not overwhelmingly documented.